# How can I send a message to a SameTime user from another system?

Tags: lotus, instant-messaging, sametime

I guess what I'm asking is what methods are available to send SameTime messages to users?  The version is the one integrated into Notes 8.5.

Is there a command line, a web service, a .Net API, a Java API, LotusScript Orr something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a free Java API available [here](http://www14.software.ibm.com/webapp/download/nochargesearch.jsp?q0=&k=ALL&S_TACT=104CBW71&status=Active&b=Lotus&sr=1&q=sametime%20sdk&ibm-search=Search).  The excerpt below is a simple example of how to send a message.

```
final STSession session = new STSession("SameTimeSender");
session.loadAllComponents();
session.start();

CommunityService comm = (CommunityService) session.getCompApi(CommunityService.COMP_NAME);
comm.addLoginListener(new LoginListener() {

    public void loggedOut(LoginEvent arg0) {
    }

    public void loggedIn(LoginEvent arg0) {
        LookupService lookup = (LookupService) session.getCompApi(LookupService.COMP_NAME);
        Resolver resolver = lookup.createResolver(true, false, true, false);
        resolver.addResolveListener(new ResolveListener() {

            public void resolved(ResolveEvent re) {
                STUser user = (STUser) re.getResolved();

                InstantMessagingService imservice = (InstantMessagingService) session.getCompApi(InstantMessagingService.COMP_NAME);

                final Im im = imservice.createIm(user, EncLevel.ENC_LEVEL_NONE, ImTypes.IM_TYPE_CHAT);
                im.addImListener(new ImListener() {

                    public void textReceived(ImEvent arg0) {
                    }

                    public void openImFailed(ImEvent arg0) {
                    }

                    public void imOpened(ImEvent arg0) {
                        im.sendText(false, "hello world!");
                    }

                    public void imClosed(ImEvent arg0) {
                    }

                    public void dataReceived(ImEvent arg0) {
                    }
                });
                im.open();
            }

            public void resolveFailed(ResolveEvent arg0) {
            }

            public void resolveConflict(ResolveEvent arg0) {
            }
        });

        resolver.resolve(recipientId);
    }
});

comm.loginByPassword(hostname, userId, password);
```